# Connect two computers on two different subnets with two separate account names via ssh without password

Tags: networking, ssh

I have two computers separated by the Internet.  I want to connect the two together from Computer 2 to Computer 1 using a SSH tunnel without requiring a password.

```
    ________                                                     ________
   |        |                                                   |        |
   |        |    ______     _____                    _______    |        |
   |________|---|______|---|_____|---/ Internet /---|_______|---|________|
  /          \   Router     Modem                    Gateway   /          \
 /____________\                                               /____________\
   Computer 1                                                   Computer 2
```

Default installs of OpenSSH for Windows are installed on both.
The router is forwarding a port to Computer 1's port 22.
Computer 1 has a user Foo on it and Computer 2 has a user Bar on it.
I can connect from Computer 2 to Computer 1 via the forwarded port, but it requires me to login using the user Foo and its password.

**Question:** Is it possible for me to connect to Computer 1 using either a user that doesn't exist in its Windows *user* database or without requiring me to type in Foo's password? I don't want to have to create a new account on Computer 1.

I've tried using the [`authorized_keys`](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/authorized_keys/) method, but I couldn't get it to work.  I think because they don't have the same network name, but I'm not sure.

NOTE that I don't want any additional HW investment.  This is to be lightweight so as to be easy to bring up and tare down.  Computer 2 shouldn't see the network of Computer 1 either.

## Additional Details

More info as to what happened when I tried to use the `authorized_keys` approach.

On Computer 1's bash terminal, we get:

```
$ ssh -N -L 127.0.0.1:8273:localhost:2812 Foo@192.x.y.z -p 2344
Foo@192.x.y.z's password:
```

Where 192.x.y.z is the ip of the router.  The user which this shell is running under is Bar.

The log on Computer 2 shows:

```
10092 2020-04-18 21:35:12.466 debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
10092 2020-04-18 21:35:12.466 debug3: spawning "C:\\Program Files\\OpenSSH\\sshd.exe" -R
10092 2020-04-18 21:35:12.469 debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 291
10092 2020-04-18 21:35:12.469 debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
10092 2020-04-18 21:35:12.469 debug3: send_rexec_state: done
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.497 debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 4, 4
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.497 Connection from 66.q.r.s port 50805 on 192.a.b.c port 22
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.498 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.498 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.498 debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.498 debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.511 debug3: spawning "C:\\Program Files\\OpenSSH\\sshd.exe" -y
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.516 debug2: Network child is on pid 9536
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.517 debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 6 config len 291
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.517 debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.517 debug3: send_rexec_state: done
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.517 debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.517 debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.517 debug3: preauth child monitor started
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug3: send packet: type 20 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug3: receive packet: type 20 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: local server KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.534 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.555 debug3: receive packet: type 30 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.560 debug3: mm_sshkey_sign entering [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.560 debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.560 debug3: mm_sshkey_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.560 debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 7 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.560 debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.560 debug3: mm_request_receive entering
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.560 debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.560 debug3: mm_answer_sign
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.563 debug3: mm_answer_sign: KEX signature 0000009666114BD0(99)
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.563 debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.563 debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.563 debug3: send packet: type 31 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.563 debug3: send packet: type 21 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.563 debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.563 debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.563 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.563 debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.563 debug3: send packet: type 7 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.563 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.580 debug3: receive packet: type 21 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.580 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.580 debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.580 debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.580 debug1: KEX done [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.646 debug3: receive packet: type 5 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.646 debug3: send packet: type 6 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.660 debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.660 debug1: userauth-request for user Foo service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.660 debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.660 debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.660 debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.660 debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.660 debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 9 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.660 debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.660 debug3: mm_request_receive entering
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.660 debug3: monitor_read: checking request 8
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.660 debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.660 debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 291
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.660 debug3: checking match for 'Group administrators' user foo host 66.q.r.s addr 66.q.r.s laddr 192.a.b.c lport 22
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.662 debug3: LsaLogonUser Succeeded (Impersonation: 0)
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.662 debug1: user foo matched group list administrators at line 89
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.662 debug3: match found
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.662 debug3: reprocess config:90 setting AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.662 debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.662 debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 9
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.663 debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.663 debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for Foo [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.663 debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.663 debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 4 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.663 debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.663 debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.663 debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 2.930ms, delaying 4.950ms (requested 7.880ms) [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.663 debug3: mm_request_receive entering
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.663 debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.663 debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.663 debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.668 debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.668 debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.682 debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.682 debug1: userauth-request for user Foo service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.682 debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.682 debug2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.682 debug2: userauth_pubkey: valid user Foo querying public key rsa-sha2-512 AAAAB3NzaC1...ySSBnSMShEX9WWNsp [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.682 debug1: userauth_pubkey: test pkalg rsa-sha2-512 pkblob RSA SHA256:xfY86q...5lmGM [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.682 debug3: mm_key_allowed entering [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.682 debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 22 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.682 debug3: mm_key_allowed: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYALLOWED [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.682 debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 23 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.682 debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.682 debug3: mm_request_receive entering
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.682 debug3: monitor_read: checking request 22
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.683 debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.683 debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key_from_blob: 00000096661668C0
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.683 debug1: trying public key file __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.683 debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys error:2
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.683 debug1: Could not open authorized keys '__PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys': No such file or directory
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.683 debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: publickey authentication test: RSA key is not allowed
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.683 Failed publickey for Foo from 66.q.r.s port 50805 ssh2: RSA SHA256:xfY86q...5lmGM
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.683 debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 23
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.683 debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg rsa-sha2-512 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.683 debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.683 debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 0.932ms, delaying 6.948ms (requested 7.880ms) [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.690 debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.695 debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.713 debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.713 debug1: userauth-request for user Foo service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.713 debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.713 debug2: input_userauth_request: try method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.713 debug1: keyboard-interactive devs  [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.713 debug1: auth2_challenge: user=Foo devs= [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.713 debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices '' [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.713 debug2: auth2_challenge_start: devices  [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.713 debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.713 debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 0.000ms, delaying 7.880ms (requested 7.880ms) [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.721 debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
9680 2020-04-18 21:35:12.721 debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
```

Comment: I will delete my answer (time tested and good). I think you will wind up with a very insecure connection (if you can do it at all with out allowing the other end to have internet access. So I tried (and I know what I suggested works)

Comment: Thanks for your input @John.  I don't see how this would be insecure.

Comment: The internet is a dangerous place to hook up disparate computer a world away just with raw connections at the router. That is what I have seen in years of doing this. Good luck.

Comment: @John, the connections are not raw, they are encrypted.

Comment: “I've tried using the 'authorized_keys' method, but it doesn't work.  I think because they don't have the same network name.” Why? Were the permissions for the `.ssh/` directory `700` and the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file `600`.

Comment: Hi @JakeGould, yes I did set the permissions. I've also updated the question with the log information.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

1. To make this work, one computer needs a reliable public IP address, which one of your ISPs may or may not provide. If neither computer 1 nor computer 2 has a public IP address, and you can port forward to the computer behind whatever hardware (home router etc.) is on this IP address, your setup won't work without additional hardware (a third computer with a public IP address somewhere, possibly "in the cloud" and paid for).
2. I am extremely confused that `ssh -N -L 127.0.0.1:8273:localhost:2812 Foo@192.x.y.z -p 2344` with 192.x.y.z being the address of the router next to computer 1 produces anything on computer 2 at all. What this command does is to connect computer 1 to the router. It doesn't connect computer 1 to computer 2.

   One possible explanation is that somebody else at the same time tried to connect to computer 2 via ssh and failed, and what you see in the logs is purely coincidental. (It also shows you that there are people out there that will try to connect to your computers visible on public IP addresses, and if you don't know how to secure your computer, sooner or later it will be hacked)
3. Looking at

   > The router is forwarding a port to Computer 1's port 22.

   that will only work if you run `ssh` on Computer 2, and connect to the public IP address of the router next to Computer 1.
4. What you need to do instead to debug the problem is to just plainly login from computer 1 to computer 2 via ssh, and see if that works. (Or, if computer 1 has a public IP address for the router, and computer 2 hasn't, then from computer 2 to computer 1).

   So from computer 1, do `ssh Foo@computer2`, where `computer2` is the public IP address of computer 2, and Foo an account on computer 2. If that works, you can use a variation of that command to establish the tunnel. If it doesn't work, look at the logs and figure out why it doesn't work.

---

**Edit**

Port forwarding is normally used to pass on **incoming** connections into the home router to a computer in a home network. This is needed because home routers do network address translation (NAT), and the computers behind it are not visible to the outside.

It is **not** needed for the reverse direction, and I am surprised you were even able to set this up (all home router UIs I have seen only work for incoming connections).

So while this explains why you can connect to your router from computer 1 and end up on computer 2, this also adds an extra complication - now your home computer also has to translate returning connections, which it may or may not correctly do.

So please disable port forwarding on the home router for computer 1, connect directly from computer 1 to computer 2, and then edit your question with this command (I assume `ssh Foo@a.b.c.d -p 2344`, where `a.b.c.d` is the public IP address of computer 2).

The next step is to get this working **without a password** and **without the tunnel**. The trick to do debugging is to keep things simple, and do it step by step. The more complications you can remove from each step, the easier it is to pinpoint problems.

So make sure you have the public and private key files in `~/.ssh/` on computer 1 with the right permissions. Make sure you have copied the public key to the `authorized_keys` file of account `Foo` (the log you included only shows that it's trying to read the `authorized_keys` file of the administrator account, and fails, and Foo may or may not be the Administrator's account, you didn't say). Also make sure to use `ssh -v` to connect, so you can also see on the client side what's happening, and where the problem is.

If Foo is indeed the Administrator's account, then your first problem is that you didn't put the public key into `__PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys` on computer 2.

Comment: **1)** Yes. I'm aware of this. **2)** This is a port forward command. I'm forwarding port 8273 on my local machine to port 2812 on the remote machine through the ssh tunnel which connects to port 2344 through the router at address 192.x.y.z which forwards it to Computer 1's ssh port 22. I stated this in my question, which you are referencing in your point 3. **3)** Yes, that is exactly what I am doing. **4)** I already stated I did that: *"I can connect from Computer 2 to Computer 1 via the forwarded port, but it requires me to login using the user Foo and its password."*

Comment: *"One possible explanation is that..."*.  Sorry, no, I have no problem connecting to Computer 1.  I think you are misunderstanding my question.  I just want to connect to Computer 1 without creating a new user on it or requiring that I type in Foo's password.

Comment: *"Port forwarding is normally used to pass on incoming connections into the home router to a computer in a home network."* That's exactly what I am doing.  *"now your home computer also has to translate returning connections, which it may or may not correctly do."* No, it does not.  This is a communication channel that is initiated from Computer 2 and can get responses from Computer 1 through the existing connection.  I don't need the other direction.

Comment: *"...connect directly from computer 1 to computer 2,"* Can't. Not near me. *"The next step is to get this working **without a password** and **without the tunnel.**"* I want a secure connection over the Internet without requiring me to type in a password.  Why do you want to remove the tunnel? *"Foo may or may not be the Administrator's account,"* Yes, it may or may not be. In my current setup it is, but may not be in a future setup. *"If Foo is indeed the Administrator's account..."* I placed them in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the account.  Shouldn't that work?